# Meaning of execute action against a document on node when action is sending mail in Alfresco 4?

Tags: email, alfresco

When I have code:

```
var mail = actions.create("mail");
mail.parameters.to = "...";
mail.parameters.subject = "...";
mail.parameters.from = "...";
mail.parameters.text = "some text, in case template is not found";
//// execute action against a document   
var doc = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/eafb46a7-a139-42e1-b297-71402d279b68");
mail.execute(doc);
```

I am curious, what is the meaning of providing node for execution of sending an email? Does this affect something somewhere or it doesn't make change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions typically need a context to run against. That context is usually a node (like a folder or a document). In this case, it allows the action and the freemarker mail template to pull properties from the document. Like maybe you want your email to have the name of the document or some other metadata.

Whether or not the "actioned upon node" is affected by having the action run against it is dependent on the code in the action. In the case of the mail action it should not be modifying the node.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know by any chance if sending of emails is done asynchronically?

Comment: Actions themselves can be set to run asynchronously. What I don't know is if, within the mail action, the actual sending of the mail blocks the execution of the action or not. I've never noticed.